# Python: re.sub, attempting to sub: "001 : Unknown, testing" with "Flows\Temporary\001 : Unknown, testing" gives bad escape \T at position 5

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

```
import re

actual_string = "001 : Unknown, testing"

pattern_sub = r"Flows\Temporary\001 : Unknown"
pattern_to_sub = "001 : Unknown"
actual_string = re.sub(pattern_to_sub, pattern_sub, actual_string)
print(actual_string)
```

**Error:** line 1024, in parse_template
raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re.error: bad escape \T at position 5

**Expected Outcome:** Flows\Temporary\001 : Unknown, testing

Answer (score 0):

Need to use **re.escape**
Below example works for me:

```
cat re_issue.py
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import re

actual_string = "001 : Unknown, testing"

pattern_sub = r"Flows\Temporary\001 : Unknown"
pattern_to_sub = "001 : Unknown"
actual_string = re.sub(pattern_to_sub, re.escape(pattern_sub), actual_string)
print(actual_string)
```

```
re_issue.py
Flows\Temporary\001\ :\ Unknown, testing
```

In order to get expected output, additional work should be done:

```
cat re_issue1.py
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import re

actual_string = "001 : Unknown, testing"

pattern_sub = r"Flows\Temporary\001:Unknown"
pattern_to_sub = "001 : Unknown"
actual_string1 = re.sub(pattern_to_sub, re.escape(pattern_sub), actual_string)
pattern_sub1 = " : "
pattern_to_sub1 = ":"
actual_string2 = re.sub(pattern_to_sub1, pattern_sub1, actual_string1)
print(actual_string2)
```

```
re_issue1.py
Flows\Temporary\001 : Unknown, testing
```